# How to start my application automatically when i start Hotspot in Android

Tags: android, wifi

Here i develop one application that use HotSpot, when i start hotSpot my application start automatically in Android Device ?

Comment: There are no methods in the Android SDK pertaining to the WiFi hotspot feature

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to run a Java project within Eclipse. Try right-click on the project, "Run as..." -> "Java Application". This runs the project using the Java virtual machine specified in "Project properties -> Java build path -> Libraries".